# 2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

**The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/2019-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Web Applications is scheduled for an election [next week, August 5th](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/4). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until August 5th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 6):

If there are fewer than 5 active/willing close voters at any given time on the site, how would you intervene and/or manage the close votes queue?

Answer (score 5):

Web Applications seems to have more than its fair share of "drive by" users; users who ask one question and just disappear. What are your ideas for getting some of those users to stick around and become productive community members? How will you use the moderator tools to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Discussions about the site on Meta Web Apps always only seem to be among the same two or three users. How will you encourage other regular users to engage on Meta and help drive the direction of the site?

Answer (score 4):

The scope of Web Application was evolved over the years. What do you think about the current scope? Should we keep it as is over the next couple of years or should we discuss it before 2019 ends?

Answer (score 4):

What is your basis for determining whether a comment is "unfriendly or unkind" versus one that's "harassment, bigotry, or abuse"?

Answer (score 3):

What is an improvement project you want to take on that is only possible with Moderator tools?

Answer (score 3):

Which criteria do you examine before migrating a question?

Answer (score 3):

In your opinion, what is the biggest problem/challenge Web Applications is currently facing? How would you propose to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 2):

Should the reputation score of the user be a factor in any moderator decisions that you make?

Answer (score 0):

What Web Applications tags you follow and why?

Answer (score -1):

Besides Web Applications ;) which is your favorite Stack Exchange's site and why?